# Access php, mysql site in Local area network

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

It seems a bit confusing for me. However, I developed an application with php and mysql and I am using xampp. Now I want to access it through LAN. I googled it and found that somebody is suggesting to change **httpd.conf** file...

`<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
  Order allow, deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>`

Somebody is suggesting to access the server through IP like...
`192.168.1.3/xampp/htdocs/mywebfolder/`
from the client machine where 192.168.1.3 is the IP address of my server.

Somebody is suggesting to edit the `.htaccess` file and put the below code there...

`order allow, deny
allow from all`

Now my questions are...

1. How should I access the application over LAN ?
2. Should I install xampp on server machine and access it from the client machines through IP

or

1. Should I install xampp on every machine and access the server (How ?)

For your kind information, I have a php file named appl_config.php where I put the connection information...

`define("APPL_IP", "localhost");
  define("APPL_USER", "root");
  define("APPL_PWD","xxxxxx");
  define("APPL_DATABASE","application");`

or should I put the server IP here `define("APPL_IP", "localhost");` ? and for that, should I install xampp in every machine ?

**I am completely confused. What Should I do ?**

Answer (score 0):

You have only to install xampp in your server machine and access it from your clients using the ip of the server machine 192.168.1.3/mywebfolder/

The server machine must allow connection to the http port 80. (check the firewall configuration of your server machine)